# SQL Server Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL Server Express machine using Windows authentication.
I´m logged on with a user with username Administrator, but when logging in, I get the error message:

```
Login failed for user guest ...
```

Why is not using the Administrator account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Authentication to work, the target machine has to be on a domain where your Windows credentials will be recognized. If the server is outside of your organization's control, it will not recognize your credentials and you will have to use a Sql Server user ID and password to log in.

Comment: I´m not in a doiman. Both are in a workgroup, and i trying using the same account (username and password) in both machines.

Comment: What are you connecting from? SQL Mgmt Studio or ASP.NET or some other connection?

Comment: I should post Answers o comments?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Express by default only allows local connections - you *can* enable it, but you have to explicitly do so.

See these:

- [SQL Server Express team blog: how to enable Express to accept remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx).
- [How to enable Remote Connection on SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/)

Comment: Remote connections are enabled beacause i can connect using sql server auth.